# Android google maps,google places, northern latitude exceeds southern latitude

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

I am using google maps and use JSON to parse cafe around my location from google places. When I start navigation to the chosen a cafe from my current location 95% cafe I get a polyline but on some I get error like northern latitude exceeds southern latitude and app crashes.

Here is my logcat:

```
07-07 18:11:46.037: E/AndroidRuntime(25854): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-07 18:11:46.037: E/AndroidRuntime(25854): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: southern latitude exceeds northern latitude (30.7223365 > 30.722303)
07-07 18:11:46.037: E/AndroidRuntime(25854):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.fq.a(Unknown Source)
07-07 18:11:46.037: E/AndroidRuntime(25854):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds.<init>(Unknown Source)
07-07 18:11:46.037: E/AndroidRuntime(25854):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds.<init>(Unknown Source)
07-07 18:11:46.037: E/AndroidRuntime(25854):    at com.example.google_map_ex.MainActivity.findDirections(MainActivity.java:285)
07-07 18:11:46.037: E/AndroidRuntime(25854):    at com.example.google_map_ex.MainActivity$JSONParse$1.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:366)
07-07 18:11:46.037: E/AndroidRuntime(25854):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:301)
07-07 18:11:46.037: E/AndroidRuntime(25854):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1490)
07-07 18:11:46.037: E/AndroidRuntime(25854):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3275)
07-07 18:11:46.037: E/AndroidRuntime(25854):    at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:4518)
07-07 18:11:46.037: E/AndroidRuntime(25854):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
07-07 18:11:46.037: E/AndroidRuntime(25854):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-07 18:11:46.037: E/AndroidRuntime(25854):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-07 18:11:46.037: E/AndroidRuntime(25854):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5283)
07-07 18:11:46.037: E/AndroidRuntime(25854):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-07 18:11:46.037: E/AndroidRuntime(25854):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-07 18:11:46.037: E/AndroidRuntime(25854):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
07-07 18:11:46.037: E/AndroidRuntime(25854):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
07-07 18:11:46.037: E/AndroidRuntime(25854):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 36):

Make use of LatLngBounds.Builder class to include your LatLng using .include(). It will prevent this error.

```
LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
builder.include(currentLocation).include(streetLocation);

//Animate to the bounds
CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(builder.build(), 100);
mMap.moveCamera(cameraUpdate);
```

Answer (score 3):

This exception basically happens while creating LatLngBounds object with wrong LatLng points. southwest Latlong should be first and northwest should be 2nd parameter.
[check this link](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLngBounds#public-constructors)

Answer (score 1):

First , I'am Chinese ,and I use the Gaode Map（aMap.com）,and while I run this

```
aMap.addPolyline(new
PolylineOptions().add(drawLineLastLatlng,latlng).width(10)            
.color(Color.argb(255, 1, 255, 255)))
```

the Exception "southern latitude exceeds northern latitude" occurs; then I check the class  and find the sentence at LineNumber 35, then I change my codes like this ,and questions resolved :

```
if(drawLineLastLatlng!=null&&drawLineLastLatlng.latitude!=latlng.latitude){                                               
                if(latlng.latitude>drawLineLastLatlng.latitude){
                    aMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().add(drawLineLastLatlng,latlng).width(10)
                            .color(Color.argb(255, 1, 255, 255)));
                }else{
                    aMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().add(latlng,drawLineLastLatlng).width(10)
                            .color(Color.argb(255, 1, 255, 255)));
                }
            }
```

Comment: maybe there's some grammar error , please anyone point't't me

Answer (score 0):

Find this line in your code:

```
mMapView.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(new LatLngBounds(pointA, pointB), 50));
```

and change it to this:

```
mMapView.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(new LatLngBounds(pointB, pointA), 50));
```

Switch the two points, it will solve it!

Edit: of course, you will need some method to check if the switch is needed or not, but it depends on your implementation and app logic. Dummy solution is to use try-catch and switch the points if it would crash.